# Extract and rename zip file folder

Tags: python, zip, directory, extract

I would like to extract in python a specific folder from a zip file and then rename it after the original file name.

For example I have a file called `test.zip` containing several folders and subfolders:

```
xl/media/image1.png
xl/drawings/stuff.png
stuff/otherstuff.png
```

I want the content of the media folder extracted to a folder called test:
`test/image1.png`

Comment: the boilerplate question: What have you tried so far? Mention it in the question if you have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

- the [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile) module, particularly [`ZipFile.extractall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall)
- [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)
  to get `test1` from the string `test1.zip`
- [`tmpfile.mkdtemp()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) to create a temporary directory
- [`shutil.move()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to move entire directory trees.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Usage:
./extract.py test.zip
"""

from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import sys
import tempfile
import shutil


ROOT_PATH = 'xl/media/'

zip_name = sys.argv[1]
zip_path = os.path.abspath(zip_name)
extraction_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.splitext(zip_name)[0])
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()


with ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zip_file:
    # Build a list of only the members below ROOT_PATH
    members = zip_file.namelist()
    members_to_extract = [m for m in members if m.startswith(ROOT_PATH)]
    # Extract only those members to the temp directory
    zip_file.extractall(temp_dir, members_to_extract)
    # Move the extracted ROOT_PATH directory to its final location
    shutil.move(os.path.join(temp_dir, ROOT_PATH), extraction_dir)

# Uncomment if you want to delete the original zip file
# os.remove(zip_path)

print "Sucessfully extracted '%s' to '%s'" % (zip_path, extraction_dir)
```

Use [`try..except`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) blocks to deal with the various exceptions that can happen when creating directories, removing files and extracting the zip.

Comment: Thanks, This works when I specify zip_name = 'test.zip'  but with sys.argv[1] I get an Error: list index out of range

Comment: See **Usage** at the top of the file. You're supposed to give the zip file name as the first argument on the command line (for this example). If that's not the way you want to use it, change it to get the filename from wherever you need to.